# Issue after deploying ASP.NET Web API to production

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I tested ASP.NET Web API in local environment with IIS Express and on other server with full IIS. At both places, token api and post api is working fine. I am using System.Web.Http namespace as suggested. However, after deploying it to shared hosting server, I am getting below error:

Token API:

`"error": "unsupported_grant_type"`

Post API (method with [HttpPost] of System.Web.Http):

`"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."`

Post API code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] Employee emp)
{
    ...
}
```

I am using default Routing available in WebApiConfig.cs as shown below. Not sure whether it matters as I am already decorating API method with Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I tried deploying with FileSystem method (Upload files to server and configure application in IIS) and Web Deploy method to directly deploy API to server. I am using Postman to test and using the same Http Method (Post) and body that I use while testing it locally.

What could be difference between local IIS Express/IIS and shared hosting server IIS that causes this issue?

Comment: the error message says you're using a GET request to access a POST endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the hosting provider had secondary URL which needs to be used instead of public URL. I replaced public URL with secondary URL in my API call and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `"error": "unsupported_grant_type"` means you used the wrong parameter in your request, I suggest you could re-check your request header or body to make sure you have used the right parameter type.

The `"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."` error means you used the get method instead of post to send the request.

If you use the post really, I suggest you could use Fail request tracing to see what has happened when you use the postman to send the request. [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

`